# What advantages or differences do lucky Pokémon have?

Tags: pokemon-go

With the latest update, Niantic added a brand new kind of quality for Pokémon.

[image]

Will they appear in the wild as shiny Pokémon do?
Can all Pokémon right now be lucky?
Are there any differences apart from the background effect?
Will there be a noticeable difference when on the map?
Will a lucky Pokémon be for everyone or randomly for each user (like shiny)?

Answer (score 15):

To answer your questions, based on the patch notes and the official blog:

> Will they appear on the wild as shiny pokemons do?

No, only pokemon that are traded can get the lucky trait.

> Can all pokemon right now be lucky?

As it looks right now, any pokémon that can be traded can get the lucky trait.

> Are there any differences apart from the background effect?

Lucky pokémon require 50 % less stardust to power up than pokémon without the lucky trait.

> Will there be a noticeable difference when on the map?

Not applicable since lucky pokémon don't appear in the wild.

> Will a lucky pokemon be for everyone or randomly for each user (like shiny)?

Lucky pokémon are a random chance when trading, with a higher chance for pokémon which have been in storage for a while. When a trade triggers the Lucky trait, both pokémon receive the trait.

Source: https://www.polygon.com/pokemon-go/2018/7/23/17602604/pokemon-go-update-lucky-pokemon and the links within.

Comment: Will the discount be only for stardust and not candy?

Comment: @SysDragon the official blog only mentions stardust, not candy.

Comment: I wonder what the max time length is for the Pokemon who have been in storage for a while is. I have a few Pokemon that have been in my storage since Pokemon Go's launch date

Comment: This answer is out of date and now incomplete. I came here looking for details about IV rerolling, which turning lucky affects.